# Import Error while executing spyder3-Beta version- It can't find opencl 2.1

Tags: apt, python, cuda, opencl, spyder

I installed python3 and pyopencl on ubuntu 18.04, now I want to use spyder to execute my codes, but it gives me an error while doing that:

**ImportError: /usr/local/cuda-10.0/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libOpenCL.so.1: version `OPENCL_2.1' not found (required by /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pyopencl/_cffi.abi3.so)**

I think this is a simple problem, but I can't solve it, since I have no experience with those programs.

Can anyone help me, please?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to install the python opencl libraries . Try running

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pyopencl
```

Comment: I did install python3-pyopencl, but it still doesn't work.